# How to duplicate a TDengine cluster?

Tags: tdengine

I want to keep two TDengine clusters and make them with the same data synced. How can I make it without changing my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL command to modify database replication:

```
    ALTER DATABASE db_name REPLICA 2;
```

Refer to the official documentation:
REPLICA parameter refers to the number of replicas of the modified database, and the value range is [1, 3]. For use in a cluster, the number of replicas must be less than or equal to the number of DNODE.